# Anormally exit form bash script

Tags: bash

If a script for use another script for rsync backups, type Time Machine.

But when finish first user program stop

backup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
while read A; do
    echo $A
    ssh backupuser@host.backups "[[ -d /Volumes/MACBACKUP/desarrollo_backups/$A ]] || mkdir /Volumes/MACBACKUP/desarrollo_backups/$A; touch /Volumes/MACBACKUP/desarrollo_backups/$A/backup.marker"
    bash /home/vagrant/rsync_tmbackup.sh $A/ backupuser@host.backups:/Volumes/MACBACKUP/desarrollo_backups/$A/
done < cuentas.txt
```

File cuentas.txt

```
account1
account2
..
accountN
```

When run backup.sh

```
account1  # comment first iteration on while
rsync_tmbackup: Previous backup found - doing incremental backup from backupuser@host.backups:/Volumes/MACBACKUP/desarrollo_backups/account1/2016-11-03-075246
rsync_tmbackup: Creating destination backupuser@host.backups:/Volumes/MACBACKUP/desarrollo_backups/account1/2016-11-03-080415
rsync_tmbackup: Starting backup...
rsync_tmbackup: From: castris
rsync_tmbackup: To:   backupuser@host.backups:/Volumes/MACBACKUP/desarrollo_backups/account1/2016-11-03-080415
rsync_tmbackup: Running command:
rsync_tmbackup: rsync  -e 'ssh -p 22 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null' -D --compress --numeric-ids --links --hard-links --one-file-system --itemize-changes --times --recursive --perms --owner --group --log-file '/home/vagrant/.rsync_tmbackup/2016-11-03-080416.log' --link-dest='/Volumes/MACBACKUP/desarrollo_backups/account1/2016-11-03-075246' -- 'castris/' 'backupuser@host.backups:/Volumes/MACBACKUP/desarrollo_backups/account1/2016-11-03-080415/' | grep -E '^deleting|[^/]$'
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.1.33' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
rsync_tmbackup: Backup completed without errors. # Here finish first iteration on while, and muts be with second iteration, but bash end while
```

And stop, instead made backup for next user account2

Answer (score 1):

could you use "ssh -n" as below;

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
while read A; do
echo $A
ssh -n backupuser@host.backups "[[ -d /Volumes/MACBACKUP/desarrollo_backups/$A ]] || mkdir /Volumes/MACBACKUP/desarrollo_backups/$A; touch /Volumes/MACBACKUP/desarrollo_backups/$A/backup.marker" 
bash /home/vagrant/rsync_tmbackup.sh $A/ backupuser@host.backups:/Volumes/MACBACKUP/desarrollo_backups/$A/
done < cuentas.txt
```

> man ssh ;
>
> -n      Redirects stdin from /dev/null (actually, prevents reading from stdin).  This must be used when ssh is run in the background.  A
>   common trick is to use this to run X11 programs on a remote machine. 
>   For example, ssh -n
>                shadows.cs.hut.fi emacs & will start an emacs on shadows.cs.hut.fi, and the X11 connection will be automatically
>   forwarded over an encrypted channel.  The ssh program will be put in
>   the background.  (This does not work
>                if ssh needs to ask for a password or passphrase; see also the -f option.)

Comment: ssh -n not resolve. Problem is "after" run bash program rsync_tmbackup.sh, not after run ssh command. Thanks.

Comment: @abkrim, you also use ssh command in rsync_tmbackup.sh. could you also change this in your script; rsync  -e 'ssh -n -p ...

Comment: Why? I don't like run a ssh command. My question it's other. Question it's a about fail bash script after run first iteration on while. ssh it's a line of program. bash ... it's OTHER line on bash script.

Comment: @abkrim; ssh command consumes all your remaining lines, so only run first loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure @MustafaDOGRU is right about the basic problem: when the loop starts, `read` reads the first line of cuentas.txt (as expected), but then something in the middle of the loop reads the rest of the file so when the script tries to `read` the next line... there's nothing left, and so it figures it's done and exits. Mustafa's approach was to try to figure out what part of the middle of the loop was reading and get it to stop, but it looks like there are multiple things doing it, and tracking them down may be annoying. But there's another way: pass the file's contents over something other than the standard input:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
while read -u3 A; do
    echo $A
    ssh backupuser@host.backups "[[ -d /Volumes/MACBACKUP/desarrollo_backups/$A ]] || mkdir /Volumes/MACBACKUP/desarrollo_backups/$A; touch /Volumes/MACBACKUP/desarrollo_backups/$A/backup.marker"
    bash /home/vagrant/rsync_tmbackup.sh $A/ backupuser@host.backups:/Volumes/MACBACKUP/desarrollo_backups/$A/
done 3< cuentas.txt
```

The `3< cuentas.txt` directs cuentas.txt to file descriptor #3 rather than standard input (which is fd #0), and the `read -u3` reads from fd #3, so those should work properly together. Since fd #3 is normally unused, the chance of anything in the middle of the loop messing with it is pretty small.

Comment: Ok. All roght. I put a other script. This script same process, but not run bash /home/vagrant/rsync_tmbackup.sh. Result? Of course, run all iterations without any problem. I've a lot of scripts with loops, for running several process o remote machines, and this it's first time with this issue. 
http://paste.tamainut.info/view/e6766181 This code, execute remote command, create remote dirs, and after

Comment: @abkrim I'm not sure I'm understanding you correctly, but if some scripts work without needing the fd 3 trick, it's because nothing inside the loop reads from standard input. In general, `while read A; do ... done <file` *might* work depending on what's inside the loop; but `while read -u3 A; do ... done 3<file` *will* work, for almost any loop contents.